# Jquery showing and deleting message

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
.newsUpdateComplited{
height: auto;
background-color: #C5FFB2;
border:1px solid black;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-top:10px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding:3px;
visibility:hidden;
```

This is my css
I would like to show it and after few sec delate it.
How to do it. I was looking for some tutorials but I didn't find anything good.
Can anybody help me please

Comment: Where is the JQuery? You need to include code in your question.

Comment: this is CSS, what does it have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Im looking for somebody who will explain me how to make it with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just set a timer on it. This would be 4 seconds.

```
$('.newsUpdatedComplited').show();
setTimeout($('.newsUpdatedComplited').hide(), 4000);
```

You may need to change the **visibility:hidden;** to be **display:none** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the native Javascript function `setTimeout` for this.
`setTimeout` needs to parameters. The 1st is a function, and the second is how long to wait in milliseconds. This will have it wait 3 seconds to show:

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $('.newsUpdateComplited').show();
}, 3000 );
```

You can also use jQuery's `fadein` for a smoother effect:

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $('.newsUpdateComplited').fadeIn();
}, 3000 );
```

And also, if you insert this code before the actual dom-element `.newsUpdateComplited` you need to add the jQuery's DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('.newsUpdateComplited').fadeIn();
    }, 3000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already a JQuery answer and a Javascript answer. For the sake of diversity given the lack of clarity in the question, I wanted to suggest a pure CSS alternative!

You could specify a CSS keyframe animation, like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

and then add it to your `newsUpdate` element:

```
-webkit-animation-name: animation;
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4uptfrk/)!

> Disclaimer: the support for doing it this way is terrible.

Comment: This is nice but I would like to work with Display:none

Comment: You should achieve the same effect by changing the `height` of the animated element. [Check this out.](http://jsfiddle.net/r4uptfrk/1/)